# Finding number in a string table mysql statement

Tags: mysql

I have a table which is

table A

```
|noid    |
|ab123bs |
|a22a    |
|cc123cc |
```

I want to find '123' in that table

I have tried mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM table A WHERE '123' LIKE '%noid%' -not working
```

I also have tried mysql

```
SELECT * FROM table A WHERE '123' LIKE concat('%',noid,'%') -not working
```

Comment: you should find the column name: `where 'noid' like '%123%'`

Comment: thank you. I thought mysql only work when small string search in big string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from table A where nokp like '%123%';
```